ViewPager2 and RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView – Scrolling Stops When Function Called
I'm working on an Android layout where I have a ViewPager2 and RecyclerView nested inside a NestedScrollView. I've encountered an issue when trying to call a function during scrolling: the scrolling stops, and I need to release my touch to continue scrolling. This disrupts the user experience, as the RecyclerView doesn't smoothly continue its scrolling.
Here's the code snippet I currently have:
vscroll1.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        int stickyHeaderTop = linear_head.getTop();
        FaFragmentAdapter adapter = (FaFragmentAdapter) viewpager1.getAdapter();
        Fragment currentFragment = adapter.getFragment(viewpager1.getCurrentItem());
        RecyclerView recyclerView = currentFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
        if (scrollY >= stickyHeaderTop) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(false); // Unfreeze RecyclerView when scrolled past header
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(true); // Freeze RecyclerView before header
        }
    }

});

Issue:
When scrolling, the RecyclerView within the current fragment of the ViewPager2 stops scrolling as soon as my function is called: recyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(). To continue scrolling, I need to release my touch and start scrolling again.
Questions:

How can I maintain smooth scrolling in the RecyclerView within ViewPager2 while calling functions during the scroll?

I use ChatGPT to make my question understandable, and the code is provided by ChatGPT. I'm new to Android.
What I've tried:
Using setLayoutFrozen() to control the scroll state of RecyclerView and pass the scrolling to recyclerview after scrollview reached bottom.

You should NEVER use view elements which can be used for scrolling in each other. ViewPager2 is able to scroll. RecyclerView to. And NestedScrollView also. It makes no sense to nesting them. You said you are new in Android Development. Why do you want to use the old XML Layout logic? It Would be very easier for you to use Compose (HorizontalPager and LazyColumn).

You should override onInterceptTouchEvent at your ViewPager.  Basically don't allow ViewPager to scroll if user is scrolling on RecyclerView.
Maybe something like this:
    public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {    
    
        override onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            try {
                return checkAllowSwipingOnRecyclerView(ev) && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

